# Language independent way to specify day parameter for schtasks.exe

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I'm trying to add a new task to the Windows Tasks Scheduler with `schtasks.exe`. The problem I'm having now is to specify the day of the week at which the task should run.

From what I could find out that stupid program insists on getting that argument as string abbreviation of the day name - localized to the OS language.

Other parameters accepted the English strings just fine but supplying "SUN" on a German system doesn't work. How can I work around that?

If it were just an issue of supporting the couple of languages the application is translated in that wouldn't be bad. But this way I have to expect EVERY language that tool of a tool comes in...

I'm working in c# btw...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go over all days of the week (start with March 4th 2012, which is a Sunday, and move forward until Saturday, March 10th) and format that date using the `ddd` format (short day name). That way you'll get all 7 short day names, based on your locale.

Comment: I thought this was a pretty good idea until I tried to translate "DAILY", "WEEKLY", "MONTHLY" etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can define your task in windows scheduler. Export the definition as XML(right click->export). Create a task using exported XML

```
schtasks /Create [/S <system> [/U <username> [/P [<password>]]]]
/XML <xmlfile> /TN <taskname>
```

The content of XML is language independent

Comment: I don't see this option on Windows XP. I guess it's only for Windows 7 and higher...